# ImageView with Reusable Cell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have to create custom `UITableView` and generally cell has `UIImageView`, and two `UILabel`  when image of `UIImageView` is depend upon content which i got from server. so some cell has image and some has no image.

Problem is that when i use reusability of cell then previous `UIImageView's` image remain as it.. how can i remove it and implement my content on cell proper way.

Following is mine code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *isImgOfTable =  [[self.listOfEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"EventImage"];
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    //NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        if([isImgOfTable length] > 0)
        {
            UIImageView *imgOfEvent = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
            imgOfEvent.tag = 101;
            [cell.contentView addSubview: imgOfEvent];
        }

        UILabel *lblEventTitle = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        lblEventTitle.tag = 102;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblEventTitle];

        UILabel *lblDescription = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        lblDescription.tag = 103;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblDescription];

    }

    if([isImgOfTable length] > 0)
    {
        NSString *newPath = @"";
        UIImageView *imgEvent = (UIImageView *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
        imgEvent.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        newPath = [[GeneralClass getDocumentDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[self.listOfEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"EventImage"]];
        imgEvent.frame = CGRectMake(mainX, 4, 45, 45);
        imgEvent.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(187/255.f) green:(226/255.f) blue:(255/255.f) alpha:1.0f];
        imgEvent.layer.cornerRadius = 7;
        imgEvent.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(224/255.f) green:(224/255.f) blue:(224/255.f) alpha:1.0f].CGColor;
        imgEvent.layer.borderWidth = 1;
        imgEvent.clipsToBounds = YES;
        imgEvent.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:newPath];
    }

    UILabel *lblEventTitle = (UILabel*) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:102];
    .
    .
    // Code of UILabel *lblEventTitle

    UILabel *lblEventDescription = (UILabel*) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:103];
    .
    .
    // Code of UILabel *lblEventDescription

    return cell;
}
```

**NOTE:** I must want to use reusability of cell. I dont want to fix such like

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
```

And also i am not used UITableViewCell class so may be it is not possible to call/override [prepareForReuse](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse)
Please give me you suggestion.

Comment: Just post your code which need to be attention. ie `UIImageview` related action only. Edit your code that will used to vistiors.

Comment: UILabel related code work perfect for me only previous image is not remove.

Comment: I think the much easier way to do this, is to create two custom cells in the storyboard or xib (one with an image view, and one without), and dequeue the proper one depending on whether you have an image or not.

Comment: I guess your problem with `UIImageView * imgEvent`. Is it going to display on each row?

Comment: @Ranju Patel: see Bhumeshwerkatre's comment. He has confused with your code(full code). that's why I asked you, place your code which is not working(which you assume not working), that's enough to look it your code easily.

Comment: @mani - okay Now i edited my code :)

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre - yes ,, for ex. if 1st row has image and i reuse 1st cell for 2nd cell (which has no image ) then image remain as it is.

Comment: @RanjuPatel so better go with @rdemar suggestion. Better use two cell, Or use `UIImageView * imgEvent` in each row. And based on condtion hide and show `UIImageView * imgEvent`.

Comment: @RanjuPatel : Easy fix by before you going to load with content file, just fill nil value. it will show empty instead of previous image until load.

Comment: @mani - i tried as your suggestion before some hour ago but not worked for me :(

Comment: @RanjuPatel: It should work if you place your coding in right place, Because it might not work if you place it inside this condition `if([isImgOfTable length] > 0){........}`.

Comment: @mani - I placed it At `if(cell == nil){ myCode }else{...HERE I PUTTED..}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code it help full to you.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSString *isImgOfTable =  [[self.listOfEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"EventImage"];
        NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        //NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

              UIImageView *imgOfEvent = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
              imgOfEvent.tag = 101;
              [cell.contentView addSubview: imgOfEvent];

            UILabel *lblEventTitle = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            lblEventTitle.tag = 102;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:lblEventTitle];

            UILabel *lblDescription = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            lblDescription.tag = 103;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:lblDescription];

        }

        UIImageView *imgEvent = (UIImageView *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:101];
        imgEvent.hidden=YES;
        if([isImgOfTable length] > 0)
        {
            NSString *newPath = @"";
            imgEvent.hidden=NO;
            imgEvent.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            newPath = [[GeneralClass getDocumentDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[self.listOfEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"EventImage"]];
            imgEvent.frame = CGRectMake(mainX, 4, 45, 45);
            imgEvent.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(187/255.f) green:(226/255.f) blue:(255/255.f) alpha:1.0f];
            imgEvent.layer.cornerRadius = 7;
            imgEvent.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(224/255.f) green:(224/255.f) blue:(224/255.f) alpha:1.0f].CGColor;
            imgEvent.layer.borderWidth = 1;
            imgEvent.clipsToBounds = YES;
            imgEvent.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:newPath];
        }

        UILabel *lblEventTitle = (UILabel*) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:102];
        .
        .
        // Code of UILabel *lblEventTitle

        UILabel *lblEventDescription = (UILabel*) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:103];
        .
        .
        // Code of UILabel *lblEventDescription

        return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Might i suggest subclassing UITableViewCell and using `prepareForReuse`

```
-(void)prepareForReuse
{
    labelOne = @"Default text 1";
    labelTwo = @"Default label 2";
    [imageView setImage:nil];      //Or you could set a default image?
}
```